# Object creation in multiple steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a requirement to model creation of an object (ActiveRecord and its has_many Associations) in multiple steps. Sometimes creation of an Object is done in 2 different steps.

Are there any gems which abstracts and provides support for object creation / modification which happens in multiple screens. Appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these railscasts:

[Multistep forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms) and [Wizard Forms with Wicked](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked).